# Unbounded Linear Operator on Hilbert Space.

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $(e_i)_{i\in I}$ be a Complete Orthonormal System in an (infinitely dimensional) Hilbert Space $\mathscr{H}$ (i.e. $\overline{\text{span}(e_i)_{i\in I}}=\mathscr{H}$). Prove the existence of an Unbounded  linear operator $T$ on $\mathscr{H}$ (to any other normed space) such that $T$ is still bounded on $\text{span}(e_i)_{i\in I}$.

Answer (score 1):

Since $(e_i)$ is linearly independent (in the straight linear-algebra sense; no non-trivial finite linear combination vanishes) there is a Hamel basis $(b_\alpha)_{\alpha\in A}$ for $\mathcal H$ with $(e_i)\subset(b_\alpha)$. Let $f:(b_\alpha)\to\Bbb C$ be any unbounded function such that $f(e_i)=0$. Since $(b_\alpha)$ is a basis, $f$ extends to a linear map $T:\mathcal H\to\Bbb C$.

Comment: $(e_i)_{i\in I}$ is a L.I. family in $\mathscr{H}$. By Hamel's Theorem, there exists a basis $\mathcal{B}$ of $\mathscr{H}$ containing $(e_i)_{i\in I}$. Now we want to define an unbounded operator on $\mathcal{B}$, that vanishes on $\text{span}(e_i)_{i\in I}$. However, we would have to define an unbounded operator on the basis elements $\mathcal{B}\backslash(e_i)_{i\in I}$. I know how to do this if say a countably infinite subfamily of $\mathcal{B}\backslash(e_i)_{i\in I}$ existed. $\mathcal{B}$ is uncountable (since $\mathscr{H}$ is complete), can I deduce a countably infinite subfamily?

Comment: Yes, any uncountable set contains a countably infinite subset. (This may require the Axiom of Choice, but we're already using that anyway...)